# Issue with org.mockito.Matchers.any() and jmockit

Tags: java, junit, mockito, jmockit

I have one UT using jmockit and mockito

in this UT,I have one field `@Tested TestService testService`

testService have one method using **Car** as parameter : `testService.doTest(Car car)`

then my UT: `testService.doTest(any(Car.class))`

when I debug this UT I found that `testService.doTest(any(Car.class))` always pass **null** into `doTest(car)`,what if I want **an instance of Car** in `doTest(car)`?

I tried `(Car)any()`,`(Car)anyObject()`,none of them help,any ideas?

**updated:**
I Have code:

```
class TestService{
    @AutoWired
    Dependency dependency;

    doTest(Car car){
        dependency.doSomeThing(car);
        print(car.toString());
    }
}
```

UT code:

```
@Injectable Dependency mockDependency;
@Tested TestService testService;
//record 
new Expectations() {{
    mockDependency.doSomeThing((Car)with(any));
    result=detailCar;
}};
//call verify
new Verifications(){{
    codeResult=testService.doTest((Car)with(any))
    //some codeResult assert
}};
```

this all jmockit version,I get **NullPointerException** at `car.toString()`

if I change it to:

```
new Verifications(){{
    codeResult=testService.doTest(new Car())
    //some codeResult assert
}};
```

or

```
final Car car;
new Verifications(){{
    codeResult=testService.doTest(car)
    //some codeResult assert
}};
```

I get **MissingInvocation** at `codeResult=testService.doTest(...)` seems `instance car` don't match `(Car)with(any)`

Comment: Note that using two different mocking APIs in the same test doesn't really make sense, since each API has its own ways for everything. In JMockit, for example, you would use the `any`, `anyInt`, `anyString`, etc. fields for argument matching. Another thing is that `any(Car.class)`, `anyString()`, etc. (and their equivalents in JMockit) are argument matchers to be used when *recording* or *verifying* expectations, and not anywhere else.

Comment: I first try to use all jmockit but failed,I must have done something wrong.I'll update question show more detail code

Comment: You are making several mistakes in the use of the mocking API. I would suggest to spend a few minutes with the [documentation](http://jmockit.org/gettingStarted.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mock car = mock(Car.class)` and pass this `car` in doTest. Hope it ll help
Also if you are calling any method of Car, make sure you also define the behaviour.
for eg

```
when(car.getName(anyString())).then("bmw");
```

Comment: mockito's mock can't mock final class,so I use jmockit's '@Mocked'